# azure devops library approvals and check

Tags: azure, variables, azure-devops

I added approvals and checks to variable group in library

and I don't understand how is works...

I added Approvals team , and condition of : "All approvers must approve".

but when someone else are not in team of administrators and no in the team of the approvals ,

is give hem error of :

"you do not have permissions to perform this operation on the variable group. A variable group Administrator should add you to the Administrator role."

There is nothing related to the library and approval groups in this doc.

My goal is that if there is a change in Variable it will be like in pull request there will be an approval group that you will need to approve for the change to be made.

Answer (score 0):

The situation you encountered is expected. If the user is not in the approvals Team, it should be unable to perform the operation to approve the use of the variables group.

Have a look of this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass

> Another way to control if and when a stage should run is through
> approvals and checks.

> Pipelines rely on resources such as environments, service connections,
> agent pools, variable groups, and secure files. Checks enable the
> resource owner to control if and when a stage in any pipeline can
> consume a resource. As an owner of a resource, you can define checks
> that must be satisfied before a stage consuming that resource can
> start. For example, a manual approval check on an environment would
> ensure that deployment to that environment only happens after the
> designated user(s) has reviewed the changes being deployed.

> Before the execution of a stage can begin, all checks on all the
> resources used in that stage must be satisfied.

I think you misunderstood this feature

Here I briefly explain how this feature works:

1. First, if you use variable group, the place to control permissions is here:

[image]

2. Second, 'Approvals and checks' refers to the control of the pipeline running process (this means that even the user without the above permissions, the user still can check and approve the use during the pipeline run):

[image]
[image]
If you are referring to something like this:

From your reply, do you mean the issue comes from this place?

[image]

If so, this is not how 'Approvals and checks' work.

If you need a feature, please post a feature request here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion

Comment: There is nothing related to the library and approval groups in this doc.

My goal is that if there is a change in Variable it will be like in pull request there will be an approval group that you will need to approve for the change to be made.

Comment: @Nitro5 I have updated the answer, hope that explains the feature well.